# custom values are not showing in JWT token that are returned from my API Connector in signup/signin user flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm able to pass attributes through my api connector when a user signs up threw the standard Signin/up user flow just fine to my API.  I have a value 'loyaltyId' that i've added as a custom claim in the Azure B2C portal.  In my API, I return the 'loyaltyId' that I create in my API.

[image]

In my return from my C# API I have

```
      var result = new
            {
                version = "1.0.0",
                action = "Continue",
                extension_<my b2c extension app key>_loyaltyId = loyaltyNumber,                  
            };

      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

But when it returns It's not showing my returned 'loyaltyId' in the JWT token.  It does show all the other attributes in my claims list that are selected except the 'loyaltyId'

```
  "emails": [
  "xxxxx@somewhere.com"
  ],
  "newUser": true,
 "given_name": "TestFirstName",
 "family_name": "TestLastName",
 "extension_mobilePhone": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "tfp": "B2C_1_SignUpIn"
  }.[Signature]
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API connectors in user flows don’t allow token augmentation yet. They can be used to send data you collected from the sign up page to be validated/approved by your API only.

You can use [custom policies](https://aka.ms/ief) to achieve your goal here.